# if JS wrapper objects are considered bad style, is type-checking with lodash _.isString etc. considered bad style as well?

Tags: javascript, wrapper, lodash, primitive, typeof

As other questions and answers have already noted, Google and Douglas Crockford both consider JS wrapper objects bad style and shouldn't be used.

If that's the case, should using lodash `_.isString`, which works for primitive and object-wrapped strings, just to check if something is a string, be considered bad style as well?

It seems to me some lodash functions such as these are designed primarily to be used for functional programming, e.g. `_.filter(myArray, _.isString)`, but if one is following best practices of using only primitive strings, a simple `typeof` check would suffice for the implementation.

But the lodash code for `_.isString` does much more than that:

```
 /**
     * Checks if `value` is classified as a `String` primitive or object.
     *
     * @static
     * @memberOf _
     * @category Lang
     * @param {*} value The value to check.
     * @returns {boolean} Returns `true` if `value` is correctly classified, else `false`.
     * @example
     *
     * _.isString('abc');
     * // => true
     *
     * _.isString(1);
     * // => false
     */
    function isString(value) {
      return typeof value == 'string' ||
        (!isArray(value) && isObjectLike(value) && objectToString.call(value) == stringTag);
    }
```

What was the motivation for this?  Users who use object wrappers complaining that the lodash methods didn't work on them?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what people mean by "wrapper objects". `"hello"` is a string literal but `new String("hello")` is in a wrapper object. There's no reason to use wrapper objects like that.

Comment: without/before "use strict", many functional methods like `[].map()` coerce string primitives into objects when passed as `this`, ex: `[1].map(function(a){return this}, "hello")[0]`. this is without explicitly using object wrappers, so to let the util work in that situation, it needs to handle objects. you also sometimes see people doing stuff like `x2=new x.constructor(x);`, which yields the same result as the map() example on strings. is a "String" not a "string"? i think it should be. if you don't need that capability, then as you say, `_.filter(r, a=>typeof a==="string")` is a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

I dont think using any of the underscore/lodash type checking methods is bad practice or bad style. Infact, they read quite nicely and are typically less programmer-error prone.

The motivation for making it work for string objects as well as literals is that it just simply must. Lodash is a library and in such should support what ever quirks exist in javascript.

As for why you may use string objects instead. One reason I can think of is so that you may attach properties to the string
ex:

```
var a = new String('foo bar');
a.b = 'baz';
```